# Why is my intent failling to pass data and recieving a intent.getintExtra null object failure?

Tags: java, android

I have declared my variables and gathered data on my main activity. I have set the intents and have the intents being collected on my result activity. The problem seems that the data isn't being passed from the main activity to the desired screen.

The main goal is to show the result on a new activity screen.

```java
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  //variables
    Button btnCalculate, btnReset;
    Spinner spinSpeaker;
    EditText editLength, editWidth, editHeight;
    String t1,t2,t3;

    int numLength, numWidth, numHeight, numResult=0;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        //connecting variables to GUI elements
        btnCalculate= findViewById(R.id.btnCalculate);
        btnReset = findViewById(R.id.btnReset2);
        spinSpeaker = findViewById(R.id.spinSpeaker);
        editLength= findViewById(R.id.editLength);
        editWidth = findViewById(R.id.editWidth);
        editHeight = findViewById(R.id.editHeight);




        //adding function to the calculate button
        btnCalculate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                //parsing text to integers
                t1=editLength.getText().toString();
                t2=editWidth.getText().toString();
                t3=editHeight.getText().toString();

                if (t3.equals("")) {
                    editHeight.setText("11");
                }else if (t2.equals("")) {
                    editWidth.setText("11");
                }else if (t1.equals("")) {
                    editLength.setText("11");
                }else{
                    numLength = Integer.parseInt(t1);
                    numWidth = Integer.parseInt(t2);
                    numHeight = Integer.parseInt(t3);
                }

                //alert to contact Pro design
                if ((numLength>=999)||(numWidth>=999)||(numHeight>=20)) {

                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.contactPro,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }else {
                    //calculating volume
                    numResult = numHeight * numWidth * numLength;

                    //sending data to other activities
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, Result.class);
                    intent.putExtra("varHeight", numHeight);
                    intent.putExtra("varWidth", numWidth);
                    intent.putExtra("varLength", numLength);
                    intent.putExtra("varResult", numResult);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
 //the following is the result activity
public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Pulling variables from main activity
    Intent variables = getIntent();
    //int length = variables.getIntExtra("varLength",0);
    //int width =variables.getIntExtra("varWidth",0);
    int totalResult = variables.getIntExtra("varResult",0);

    String result = String.valueOf(totalResult);
    TextView tim;

   Canvas canvas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvas = new Canvas(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        //setContentView(canvas);

        tim = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        tim.setText(result);
```

I expected that R.id.txtResult would show numResult = numHeight * numWidth * numLength; just on the second screen.

The error message I keep getting is::

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int android.content.Intent.getIntExtra(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.project.Result.(Result.java:23)

Comment: use the onCreate method to get the intentExtra

Comment: check my answer please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`getIntent()` has to be called in `onCreate()`. Change the `Result` `Activity` to this:

```
public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {

    TextView tim;

    Canvas canvas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvas = new Canvas(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        //setContentView(canvas);

        Intent variables = getIntent();
        //int length = variables.getIntExtra("varLength",0);
        //int width =variables.getIntExtra("varWidth",0);
        int totalResult = variables.getIntExtra("varResult",0);

        String result = String.valueOf(totalResult);

        tim = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        tim.setText(result);
    }
```

Comment: THANK YOU!  This worked. It makes sense now that the getIntent() needed to be called in the onCreate

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

try to get your `intent` result in your  `onCreate()`

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvas = new Canvas(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        Intent variables = getIntent();
        //int length = variables.getIntExtra("varLength",0);
        //int width =variables.getIntExtra("varWidth",0);

        int totalResult = variables.getIntExtra("varResult",0);
        ......
        ......
```

Answer (score 0):

try this Code in  the `result activity`

```
public class Result extends AppCompatActivity {



   Canvas canvas;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        canvas = new Canvas(this);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_result);
        setContentView(canvas);

    Intent variables = getIntent();
    int length = variables.getIntExtra("varLength",0);
    int width =variables.getIntExtra("varWidth",0);
    int totalResult = variables.getIntExtra("varResult",0);

       final  TextView tim  = findViewById(R.id.txtResult);
        tim.setText(totalResult+"");
```